# How to add a registry key using VBScript?

Tags: windows-registry, vbscript

I want to add a registry key (DWORD=1) in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies` using VBScript. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

An example of registry entry creation would be:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Script Center"
strValueName = "My DWORD Value"
dwValue = 13

objRegistry.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, dwValue
```

where the targets can be changed accordingly to your needs.

[Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/11/16/how-can-i-create-a-new-registry-key.aspx)

Comment: I am sorry. But i didn't understand. can you give me exact script for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet \Control\StorageDevicePolicies?

Comment: @powermun50 if you can't rewrite this script to suit your needs you probably shouldn't be editing the registry.

Comment: @MDMoore313: Very well said!

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

**Example 1**: Set the registry flag to display Hidden and System files in Windows Explorer:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myKey = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Hidden"
WshShell.RegWrite myKey,1,"REG_DWORD"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

**Example 2**: Set the registry flag to hide Hidden and System files in Windows Explorer (the default):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myKey = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Hidden"
WshShell.RegWrite myKey,0,"REG_DWORD"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

**Example 3**: Create a "default value" at `KCU\KeyName\`
Note: The trailing backslash is **required**:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\KeyName\","", "REG_SZ"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Credit to http://ss64.com